# Number suffix for short

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I write a short literal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208433/how-do-i-write-a-short-literal-in-c)

I can use `ll` to represent a long long number, I can use `u` to represent a unsigned number, etc.

Is there a number suffix for `short` type?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The C++ standard only gives these integer suffixes (2.13.1)

```
unsigned-sufﬁx: one of
u U
long-sufﬁx: one of
l L
long-long-sufﬁx: one of
ll LL
```

so no, there is no suffix for shorts.

Comment: According to the C++ standard http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal, since C++11, l or L is a suffix for "long long int".

Answer (score 5):

No there is no integer constant suffix for `short` in C.

In most expressions a `short` value is promoted to `int` so it is not so useful. You can cast an `int` integer constant to `short`, but with the integer promotions rules, chances are it will be promoted to `int`.

Comment: If you really need an expression of type `short` and want it to also be valid for the preprocessor, you can use `((short)+(expr))`.