# What does (~0L) mean?

Tags: c++, c, x11, ctypes

I'm doing some X11 ctypes coding, I don't know C but need some help understanding this.

In the C code below (might be C++ im not sure) we see `(~0L)` what does that mean? In Javascript and Python `~0` means `-1`.

```
812   int result = GetProperty(window, property_name,
813                            (~0L), // (all of them)
814                            &type, &format, &num_items, &properties);
```

Thanks

Comment: How do I write a short 0, such as 0S?
I see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208433/how-do-i-write-a-short-literal-in-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`0L` is a `long` integer value with all the bits set to zero - that's generally the definition of `0`. The `~` means to invert all the bits, which leaves you with a `long` integer with all the bits set to one.

In two's complement arithmetic (which is almost universal) a signed value with all bits set to one is `-1`.

The reason for using `~0L` instead of `-1L` is to be clearer about the intent - it's not meant to be used as a number at all, but rather as a collection of bits.

Comment: Thank you mark so much! So the number I should use in my ctypes is `11111111111111111111111111111111` if the software is 32bit and 64 1's if its 64bit `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`?

Comment: The trouble is that if the parameter you're calling is a `long long` then `~0L` only inverts some of the bits, whereas `-1`  (no suffix required) inverts all of them.

Comment: @Noitidart it depends on your definition of `long`. Microsoft defines it as only 32 bits, even for 64-bit software.

Comment: @Notidart, if it's Python ctypes just use `c_long(~0)`. The size of a `c_long` depends on the platform.

Comment: @eryksun I missed your comment back then, I'm glad I saw it now, that worked wonderfully thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise compliment of zero of long type.

Comment: I'm not a computer science guy just a hobbyist. Haha so that is like alien talk to me :P Is that `-1`? I kind of need a number to put into my ctypes :P

Comment: @No: Nearly, at least on two's complement implementations: `-1L` Anyway, why not just use the same expression in C++?

Comment: Thanks @Deduplicator I'm more confused now haha whats two's completment implmentations? haha does that mean 64bit or 32bit software? So if I put `-1` would that be ok? We don't have a `L` in ctypes.

Comment: It's all bits set to 1.

Comment: @Noitidart  it can be -1L but you can think of it like this. If a 64bit 0L is 8 bytes all zeros (and each byte's 8 bits are zeros), then the ~0L operation means you take all the 0 bits in those bytes and turn them to 1's. So for each byte that starts as [00000000] in bits, the result is [11111111].

Comment: @Noitidart `~0L` means exact as [Bill](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27596134/2410359) says.  To use -1L, etc. is less potable as `-1L` may not have a representation of all bits set.

Comment: Thank you all so much! So the number I should use in my ctypes is `11111111111111111111111111111111` correct? and if 64bit then i should use 64 1's?