# How to create a long number of all bits at 1

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

I need to pass `~0L` to my function, how can I do this, no matter what I do ~0 is being turned to `-1`

This is the C code:

```
812   int result = GetProperty(window, property_name,
813                            (~0L), // (all of them)
814                            &type, &format, &num_items, &properties);
```

This is my jsctypes:

```
var result = GetProperty(window, property_name, ctypes.long(~0), type.address(), format.address(), num_items.address(), properties.address()
```

Notice the `ctypes.long(~0)` how to make this be the `111111111111111111111111111111` for 32bit slash the 64 1's for 64bit?

Thanks

reference topic: [What does (~0L) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596116/what-does-0l-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use `ctypes.long(~0)` this is good for 32 bit and 64 bit :) Thanks to @arai.

> 21:45 noida   how to use ~0L in jsctypes?
>
> 22:07 arai    noida: 32bit or 64bit?
>
> 22:11 noida   can you show me how to do for both plz
>
> 22:17 arai    noida: I guess ctypes.int32_t(~0) and ctypes.int64_t(~0) will work
>
> 22:20 noida   -0x80000000
>
> 22:20 noida   that wont work huh?
>
> 22:20 arai    it uses ctypes.long for the parameter, so ctypes.long(~0) would be better
>
> 22:23 arai    ~0L is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, right?
>
> 22:24 noida   i thought it was: 0x7ffffff
>
> 22:29 arai    `printf("%lx\n", ~0L);` outputs "ffffffffffffffff"
>
> 22:31 arai    it would be more better to use `ctypes.long(~0)` for consistency
>
> 22:33 noida   also using the long method will be cross 64/32 bit right?
>
> 22:37 arai    "This automatically converts to an Int64 JavaScript object on all platforms, since it's unknown whether this is a 32-bit or 64-bit value. This is done for compatibility's sake."
>
> 22:37 arai    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ctypes

Answer (score 1):

declare it unsigned long, `~0UL`

Comment: I had to google this, but does ctypes.unsigned_long(~0) look right?  Be sure to declare the matching C++ code as expecting an unsigned long too.  In C++, ~0 (all bits set) is also how -1L is represented; whether it's treated as -1L or ~0UL depends on how it's declared.

Comment: Oh I thought you were a js-ctypes guy. Yeah i tried that, Im not sure its the right way to do it. Im not getting data which might have something to do with this.

Comment: no, I'm more of a C/C++/nodejs guy.  I've written nodejs plugins.  If you're not getting the data, try printing out everything you're receiving on the C side, that might help show what's happening.