# Why does passing the literal 3 choose the int overload instead of the short overload?

Tags: c++, overloading

How does C++ handle function overloading in this case?

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int x)
{
   std::cout << "integer";
}

void func(short x)
{
   std::cout << "short";
}

int main(void)
{
   func(3);
}
```

> **Output**: integer

Why is that?

Comment: Because `3` is integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a short literal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208433/how-do-i-write-a-short-literal-in-c)

Comment: The answers are correct, but don’t say why. C++ does this for backward-compatibility with C. Historically, C was designed on 16-bit DEC PDP machines and the first versions of it had no `short` type. As it got ported to new architectures and standardized, C kept the assumption that `int` is the native word length, and the most convenient default size to work with. This is also the reason for `char` and other types narrower than `int` getting automatically converted to `int` in some situations: this is faster on many machines, including the PDP.

Comment: Also, no C or C++ standard ever said exactly what the ranges of `int`, `long int` or `long long int` are, and they have been different on different architectures. So a rule that a constant has the narrowest type that can hold it would make the same simple, standard-conforming expression have different behavior on two different compilers.

Comment: @Davislor: And yet that is approximately the rule. Integral literals have the smallest type from `int, long, long long`. The inconsistency is that `short` is missing from that list.

Comment: A quick way to check the type is to output `typeid(3).name()` (you must `#include <typeinfo>` for this to work. The result would be `i` in this case. If you cast it to `short`, you'd see `s` instead.

Comment: @MSalters Typically, `int` is the platform's native size. If it doesn't fit in an `int`, you'll have to use a `long` or `long long`. But if it does fit in the native word size, that's what you want to use because it's typically what the platform handles best.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Of course. Not that it really matters in 2017. No current compiler is going to actually cast  `short s = 3` from 32 to 16 bits. The language just defines the forma semantics, and it's those semantics which are the result of 20th century technology.

Comment: @MSalters Good point.

Comment: 3 is an integer, it will not go to func(short x). It instead goes to func(int x) and returns integer.

Answer (score 58):

Constants have types too. And without a suffix to indicate otherwise, `3` is simply an `int` constant. The compiler will choose a larger type if the constant is too big, but it won't go for things smaller than an `int` by default.

Now, it just so happens, that there is no suffix to make a short constant. You'd need to add a cast if you want that particular overload to be called.

Comment: Or you create a suffix :)

Comment: `operator ""` it seems like, neat http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 29):

Literal `3` is a constant and implicitly is of type `int` by the language design.

For your `short` overloaded function execution you have to use `short` variable:

```
short s = 3;
fun(s);
```

or cast the constant properly:

```
fun((short)3);
fun(static_cast<short>(3));
```

Type `short` hasn't suffix like for example `long` (`long l = 42L;`), but you can create one.

Answer (score 17):

Because `3` is an integer.

```
fun(static_cast<short>(3));
```

would call the short version.

Or you can use user-defined literals to make a short: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208433/how-do-i-write-a-short-literal-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

You are doing

```
fun(3);
```

and *3* is a *literal constant **integer*** so the function that better matches the overload is this one

```
void fun(int x)
{
    std::cout << "integer";
}
```

feel free to play a litte with the types and casting those like:

```
fun(short(3));
fun(int(3));
// C++11
auto x = 3;
fun(x);
```

Answer (score 6):

The constant `3` has it's own type, in this case it's an `int`. You need to explicitly cast your constant to `short` if you want your overload to execute

```
fun((short)3);
```