# Literal for short or char (integers)

Tags: c

Is there a literal syntax to write a `char` or `short`? For example:

- `4`  --> int
- `4L` --> long
- `4LL` --> long long
- 4C ?
- 4H ?

Or, do you need to cast it to do the literal notation, for example:

- `(char) 4` --> char
- `(short) 4` --> short

Note: even if I write it as `'a'`, it still recognizes it as an `int` (at least when I inspect it in VS Code).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208433/how-do-i-write-a-short-literal-in-c

Comment: @vmp ok but I don't think `'\2'` evaluates to a `char` (at least it doesn't for me in my program, for me I get an int).

Comment: Well, you read the question... what about the answers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208433/ is a C++ question, but this is a C question. Character literals such as `'\2'` are `int`s in C but are `char`s in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no suffixes for short types (types narrower than `int`) and you don't need them.

Outside of preprocessor conditionals, the suffixes can be fully expressed in terms of casts or more generically casts and the ternary operator ( `0xfffffffffU` isn't equal to `(unsigned)0xfffffffff`, but it is equal to `(1?0xfffffffff:0u)` on platforms with 32-bit `unsigned`s).

In preprocessor conditionals, casts won't work, so you do need at least the `U` suffix there if you need unsigned semantics. The other suffixes, I guess, are just for convenience for when a macro needs to be used in both C and in preprocessor conditionals, although things like `((type)+42)` can also be employed in such situations (relying on keywords expanding to `0` in preprocessor conditionals).

As [Eric Pospitschil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) has pointed out, preprocessor arithmetic is done in `intmax_t`/`uintmax_t` so you don't need to widen the constants as you would in C proper to prevent some instances of undefined behavior.

Comment: Per C 2018 6.10.1 4, evaluations in `#if` statements are done with `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, so no suffixes are necessary except to make a literal unsigned.

Comment: @ps -- thanks, could you please explain the use of `?:` a bit more?

Comment: @carl.hiass The idea is that the suffix can widen the constant but not truncate it. (unlike a cast, which would truncate).

Comment: @EricPostpischil So it seems only `U` is actually needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no suffix to specify integer literals of a type smaller than `int` like you can with larger types.  The closest you can come to that would be to use a compound literal:

```
(char){4}
(short){4}
```

Even so, using such a construct wouldn't do much because in most contexts an integer type smaller than `int` would be **promoted** to `int` when used in an expression.

From section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding integer conversions:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or
> `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less
>   than  or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int` , `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If  an `int` can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as
> restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is
> converted  to  an `int`; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an
> `unsigned int`. These  are  called  the *integer promotions*. All
> other  types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions.